# Adverb position

Tags: grammar, adverbs

> English is most widely used around the world

A Canadian teacher told me that the standard English usage is like this. But I once talked with an American that used this sentence:

> English is a language used most widely around the world

He could understand me. I didn't find any grammar mistakes in the sentence.

Can any native speakers teach me the correct usage?

Comment: Languages often have more than one way to say the same thing. I'm sure this is true for your native language, as well. They're ***both*** correct.

Comment: In almost all contexts, the 'a' would be replaced by 'the' in the second example. And 'English is the most widely used language across the world' is probably what is meant.

Answer (score 3):

Both are used in standard English. Here are a few examples of use:

> It is suitable for late-fall market and is used somewhat for the southern winter crop; however, it **is used most widely** in the North for the late pack of sauerkraut. [(Farmers' Bulletin, 1928)](http://books.google.com/books?id=tGYTAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA12-PA15&dq=%22is+used+most+widely%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QQluU6OCB4HTPOftgIAE&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA)
>
> Of the analytical techniques mentioned for system safety, the fault tree technique is used most widely [Modern Accident Investigation and Analysis, 1988](http://books.google.com/books?id=NJVvvIGBsmQC&pg=PA151&dq=%22is+used+most+widely%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wwpuU-CCMafC0QWS44DQBA&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA)
>
> This dose of selegiline is used most widely in adjunctive therapy [Parkinsons's Disease: The Treatment Options, 1999](http://books.google.com/books?id=wOQf3XcExF8C&pg=PA148&dq=%22is+used+most+widely%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GwtuU9X_BPLM0AXWlIGADg&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAQ)

However, the preference is to locate *"most widely"* right after the auxiliary verb *"is"*. Here's an [ngram comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+most+widely+used%2Fis+used+most+widely&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28is%20most%20widely%20used%20/%20is%20used%20most%20widely%29%3B%2Cc0) supporting this:

[image: Imgur]