# "I'm going to finally start" or "I'm going to start finally"?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

As mentioned, which is the correct one?

> "I'm going to finally start" or 
>  "I'm going to start finally"?

It's not only this particular sentence/phrase I'm worried about. I want to know, just like the question asked, which word should come before/after another word. **Are there any grammar rules which dictate the correct way to place certain words/verbs before/after other words?**

Comment: This can help: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23105/adverb-position?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second example "I'm going to start finally" sounds odd, because "start" and "finally", near-opposites, are juxtaposed. (One almost always starts at the beginning, no matter how late one starts.)

I suggest

- I'm **finally** going to start.
  (this way, "finally" modifies "going")

  ```
          or
  ```
- "**Finally**, I'm going to start.
  (this way, "finally" modifies the whole sentence; it's a **sentence adverb**.)

Comment: This also might be improved by using _will_ instead of _going to_, and adding a bit more context. _Tomorrow, we will finally start the project._ (That sentence implies that a team has been wanting to get underway for some time, but has been unable to start before tomorrow.)

Answer (score 1):

There are many types of adverbs. What you are talking here is a *[time adverb](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-types)*. Adverbs can take position in the initial, mid or end of the sentence.

I think both the formats are okay depending upon author's style. **However,** to me, it looks that *to finally start* is more appropriate as in...

> *Executives may therefore be emboldened **to finally start** pumping up capital spending - Forbes*

---

[A side note: 'start' in such context *mostly* requires mentioning what are you starting: `I'm going to finally start '[something]'`].